# How to check box when dropdown list is selected

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I have a dropdown list which is created from a database.

I also have a checkbox list which is created from a database.

In the database i have a group setup so you can tick multiple boxes and save its value as a dropdownlist item

Is there a way to choose the dropdown list created and have it automatically tick the boxes that have been added from the database.

For Example

```
checkboxes :
option 1
option 2
option 3

dropdownlist name:

option2 
option3
```

when choosing the item in the dropdown list it marks the `option2 and option3` as selected

is this possible?

Comment: what u have tried so far?

Comment: use javascript, on dropdown use a function onchange(), and call the javascript. in javascript check the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side (when loading the page) you could use something like:

```
print "option value='{$db->value}' ($db->value==1) ? 'checked' : ''>One</option>";
```

Client side: you will need to use JavaScript to update the checkbox values